# How to configure autotest to run on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, autotest

Am working my way through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial and he says in Chapter 5 that one should configure Mac OS X to run auto test. The code he provides for OS X is:

```
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |autotest|
  autotest.add_mapping(/^spec\/requests\/.*_spec\.rb$/) do
    autotest.files_matching(/^spec\/requests\/.*_spec\.rb$/)
  end
end
```

My question is where does this file go to handle the integration? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this part](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec%3aautotest) of the tutorial.

As it says, you can either put this file in the root of the project folder, or alternatively, you can save it to your user (/Users/YOURUSERNAME/) directory, this will allow it to be used in all projects. In either case, the file should be called `.autotest`

You will need all of this in there:

```
require 'autotest/fsevent'
require 'autotest/growl'

Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |autotest|
  autotest.add_mapping(/^spec\/requests\/.*_spec.rb$/) do
    autotest.files_matching(/^spec\/requests\/.*_spec\.rb$/)
  end
end
```